# NodeJS: Execute a callback when several callbacks has been executed

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is what I need to do:

```
function myFunc(ID, callback){
    func1("foo", res => { console.log(res) });
    func2("bar", res => { console.log(res) });
    func3("batz", res => { console.log(res) });

    // Here I need to call callback(something); when all of
    // the above funcs terminated and called their callbacks.

    // I could increment/decrement a counter to know how many
    // callbacks executed, but then how could I execute a function
    // (e.g. a callback) as soon as this counter gets to 0 ?
}
```

I need a smart and clean solution if possible (because I already find the counter trick being a work-around) :)

Thanks !!

Comment: It's time for you to learn about promises and async/await.

Comment: Promises, Async functions, Etc...

Comment: Hum even if I need the 3 functions to run simultaneously ?

Comment: to run simultaneously use `await Promise.all([func1, func2, func3])`

Comment: Thank you ! I think that was exactly what I was looking for :)